# Django: Update and Create data record with inlineformset_factory

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Can someone help me i am trying to use "inlineformset_factory" i actually made it working but instead of updating the record it just duplicating the record

this is my view.py

```
def resume(request):
user = request.user.personaldetails

form1 = personalDetailsForm(instance=user)

workExpFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    personalDetails, employmentHistory, form=employmentHistoryForm, extra=3, max_num=3)

formset = workExpFormSet(instance=user)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = personalDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
    formset = workExpFormSet(request.POST, instance=user)
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.save()
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
    else:
        print(formset.errors)
    # print(formset)

return render(request, 'main/Client/resume.html', {'form1': form1, 'formset': formset})
```

My models.py

```
class personalDetailsForm(ModelForm):
profile_image = forms.ImageField(label="", widget=forms.FileInput(
    attrs={'type': 'file', 'id': 'mediaFile'}))
jobTitle = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'jobTitle'}))
fname = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'fname'}))
lname = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'lname'}))
email = forms.EmailField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'email', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'email'}))
phone = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'phone'}))
country = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'country'}))
city = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'city'}))
address = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'address'}))
birthplace = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'pdate'}))
birthdate = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'bdate'}))
nationality = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'national'}))
profSummary = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'summaryEditor'}))
postalcode = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'postal'}))

class Meta:
    model = personalDetails
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['accounts']

class employmentHistoryForm(ModelForm):
JobTitle = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control jobTitle', 'name': 'jobTitle'}))
start_date = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control startDate', 'name': 'start_date'}))
end_date = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control endDate', 'name': 'end_date'}))
employer = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control employerName', 'name': 'employer'}))
city = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control employerCity', 'name': 'city'}))
description = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control employeeEditor', 'style': 'height: 100px;', 'name': 'description'}))

class Meta:
    model = employmentHistory
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['personal']
```

and lastly my form to customize my model

```
class employmentHistoryForm(ModelForm):
JobTitle = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control jobTitle', 'name': 'jobTitle'}))
start_date = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control startDate', 'name': 'start_date'}))
end_date = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control endDate', 'name': 'end_date'}))
employer = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control employerName', 'name': 'employer'}))
city = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control employerCity', 'name': 'city'}))
description = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
    attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'form-control employeeEditor', 'style': 'height: 100px;', 'name': 'description'}))

class Meta:
    model = employmentHistory
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['personal']
```

whenever i enter/save my form data it create a record and add another record with the same data from the previous record it just multiplying the last input data... but whenever i tried just to change the last data it out put with an error :

> [{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have not included the id field inside your templates, or may have implemented it wrong (As you have not included your template code I am assuming this is the problem, which is very likely the case). Since Forms did not find any id associated with the post data, it assumes that it is a Create request instead of an edit.

Comment: what da... i have been coding for hours now it works properly thank you! I used form.non_field_errors per form in a for loop and i did not put the form.id... thank you for your answer!!